# How do I dismiss a full screen UIImageView?

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview

I am creating a UIImageView like this when a button is clicked in my app

```
CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
    CGFloat screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;

    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:selectedVariantDetail[@"fcVariantImageUrl"]]];

    UIImageView *dot =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,screenWidth,screenHeight)];
    dot.image=[UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    dot.tag = 2;
    [self.view addSubview:dot];
```

But how do I dismiss the same view when it is tapped on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `UITapGestureRecognizer` in your `UIImageView` and on its action remove the `UIImageView`.

```
//Add tap Gesture
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dismissTapGesture:)];
[dot addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
//Set userInteractionEnabled property of imageView to true because by defaults its false
dot.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

Now simply remove `UIImageView` in action method of `UITapGestureRecognizer`.

```
- (void)dismissTapGesture:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)gesture {
    [gesture.view removeFromSuperview];
}
```